# DC resistance on soldered PCB between power and ground

Tags: power-supply, pcb, ldo

I have just finished soldering a PCB I made with a couple of components (Spartan 3e FPGA), and I was checking the DC resistance between my power rails and GND to make sure they were not shorted.

I measured 10kohms between 3v3 and GND, 5kohms between 2v5 and GND and 68ohms between 1v2 and GND.

68ohms is getting me worried but at the same time that's only 17mA of current.

The power rails are generated with LDOs.

Does anyone have any opinion on this ?

Note: I haven't plugged it in yet since I don't want everything to blow up...

Comment: When you DO plug it in the first time, set the PSU current limit to your calculated current consumption (plus a small margin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are chips being powered by the power rails. They are not linear loads like resistors are so measuring resistance is quite useless. That only tells that there are no direct shorts between power rails.

Most likely the values mean that the circuit is fine.